# Hiding a UITableView header on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ipad, uisearchbar

I have a UITableView with a roughly 100pt header set in the storyboard which contains some searching and filtering functions all inside a single UIView. I'm trying to adjust the content offset so that the user has to pull down to see the header so in viewDidLoad I do this:

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.size.height)];
```

On iPhone this works perfectly, on iPad this line does nothing unless the tableHeaderView is a subclass of UISearchBar. I don't know why this case is treated differently.

Additional details:

- The view controller is a subclass of UITableViewController
- The view controller is inside a UINavigationController
- On iPad the controller is the master view controller of a UISplitViewController